# Complex SQL (Maybe Outer Joins)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables as defined below.

**Reviews table**
id
user_id
review
title
datetime

**PeopleFollows table**
id
user_id
following_user_id
datetime

I want to run 1 query to get the top 10 results by datetime. So for instance, if I have the following data:

Review table

```
1 user1  "This is my review" "title" 2011-01-10  
2 user1 "Another review" "title again" 2011-01-08
```

People Follows table

```
1 user2 user1 2011-01-09
```

I want to get the results like this:

```
Review id=2  
People follows id=1
Review id = 1
```

The only way I think I can do this is to do separate queries of X limit, then combine them to get X results.

I might need to explain a little more.

Comment: UNION won't work because I actually want to get all the review data on one row, then all the people follows data on the next row, and then reviews data again, for example.  UNION will try to union the columns into one row.

Comment: You've given sample data for one possible follower.  I would suggest offering a little more sample data to get the context a bit more.  For the "top 10".  Top 10 based on what.  People following another person. People offering the most reviews?  Most recent 10 reviews??  Yes, you are showing review ID = 2 from Jan 8 which is older than the Jan 10, but only 1 "follower" record, yet review ID = 1.  Did you mean to put "User1" because both postings were made by "user1"?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need full scans if you index both of the tables by datetime and also order each query by datetime before UNION.

```
(SELECT "Review", id, datetime FROM Reviews ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 10)
UNION 
(SELECT "People", id, datetime FROM PeopleFollows ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 10)
ORDER BY datetime DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Sorry, but I thinks this query is not going to work. What if there would be 10 results from Reviews table? In that case there would be no rows from PeopleFollows in result set.

Comment: Did not noticed last `ORDER BY datetime DESC`. Yes, this query works and much better, than mine. Nice optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION, but query won't be optimal:

```
(SELECT "Review", id FROM Reviews)
UNION
(SELECT "People", folowing_user_id FROM PeopleFollows)
ORDER BY datetime DESC
LIMIT 10
```

You can not use proper indexes in this query, it would be fullscan. So, use it at your own risk.

Better idea - not to try to merge tables. Use third cache table for this.

Comment: Just manualy created table, where your application duplicates writes to PeopleFollows and Reviews. Slower writes - faster reads, as usual.

Comment: oh so create a reviews2 and peopleFollows2?

Comment: @OMGPonies , it will be 10 results from first table only, if there are no "more recent" (bigger date) results from second, won't it?

Comment: chris - I am pretty sure he means create a third table "Events" which stores the type of event (review or follow), the id of the event, and then the datetime, indexed on datetime. Then you can just query the Events table for the top ten records sorted by datetime, and join this into PeopleFollows and Reviews to get the relevant information for each.

Comment: @chris, I mean to CREATE TABLE Recent (event_type ENUM ('new_review', 'new_follower') NOT NULL, event_object_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, ts TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY (event_type, event_object_id), INDEX t (ts)).